# Trying to get an ID of current selected menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, offset

I am trying to get the offset of the current selected menu, which can be identified by current-menu-item or current_page_item.

However everytime I try `$(".current_page_item").offset().left`, it will always return me 0 ( which is wrong), and `$(".current_page_item").attr('id')` will return me with undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Following is my menu HTML code:

```
<li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-22"><a href="http://localhost/inn/moto/">HOME</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-77" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77"><a href="http://localhost/inn/moto/about-us">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76"><a href="http://localhost/inn/moto/products">PRODUCTS</a></li>
```

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using? The code `$(".current_page_item").attr('id')` works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/1boy4uj3/

Comment: your code is working fine (http://jsfiddle.net/70e10amn/1/), there must be something wrong with your JQ version

Comment: I am using jquery v1.11.1 . Is that a problem?

Comment: Do you have other element that have the same class `.current_page_item`?

Comment: No, current_page_item is unique only to the current selected menu

Comment: The weird thing is, if I $(".current_page_item").html(), it will display the right HTML content, but it can't show the ID nor offset

Comment: is the element visible? can't get offset or dimensions of hidden elements

Comment: Yes, the element is visible, I couldn't get the id either

Comment: Weird, have you tried `$(".current_page_item").eq(0).attr('id')` just to be sure? If this returns something else than `undefined` you probably have another `.current_page_item` somewhere. (`.eq(n)` selects the `n`th instance of the class, 0 the first)

Comment: I did view source code and use Ctrl+F and there is only one occurence. But $(".current_page_item").eq(0).attr('id') returns undefined as well...

Comment: I tested it on a fiddle and it works fine. Maybe there is a conflict somewhere with other jQuery stuff. Try with no.conflict and see if it solves anything. Here is the fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/376zm2hj/